# Custom weeks (1st week starting in july), code to calculate week number and select

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have a unique situation... I have the below code which currently allows me to select a date referenced from a week, from a combo box. I want to have the week (date) selected automatically depending on which day it is. For example, it's the 3rd of December today which falls under week 22... How do I default the combo box to display week 22? Should I have done this with a different method as in future the week dates will change?

```
<select name="dateentryweek" id="entryweek2" onclick="javascript:loadWeekOnly1()">
        <option value=""></option><option value="2013-07-07">Week 1</option><option value="2013-07-14">Week 2</option><option value="2013-07-21">Week 3</option><option value="2013-07-28">Week 4</option>
        <option value="2013-08-04">Week 5</option><option value="2013-08-11">Week 6</option><option value="2013-08-18">Week 7</option><option value="2013-08-25">Week 8</option>
        <option value="2013-09-01">Week 9</option><option value="2013-09-08">Week 10</option><option value="2013-09-15">Week 11</option><option value="2013-09-22">Week 12</option>
        <option value="2013-09-29">Week 13</option><option value="2013-10-06">Week 14</option><option value="2013-10-13">Week 15</option><option value="2013-10-20">Week 16</option>
        <option value="2013-10-27">Week 17</option><option value="2013-11-03">Week 18</option><option value="2013-11-10">Week 19</option><option value="2013-11-17">Week 20</option>
        <option value="2013-11-24">Week 21</option><option value="2013-12-01">Week 22</option><option value="2013-12-08">Week 23</option><option value="2013-12-15">Week 24</option>
        <option value="2013-12-22">Week 25</option><option value="2013-12-29">Week 26</option><option value="2014-01-05">Week 27</option><option value="2014-01-12">Week 28</option>
        <option value="2014-01-19">Week 29</option><option value="2014-01-26">Week 30</option><option value="2014-02-02">Week 31</option><option value="2014-02-09">Week 32</option>
        <option value="2014-02-16">Week 33</option><option value="2014-02-23">Week 34</option><option value="2014-03-02">Week 35</option><option value="2014-03-09">Week 36</option>
        <option value="2014-03-16">Week 37</option><option value="2014-03-23">Week 38</option><option value="2014-03-30">Week 39</option><option value="2014-04-06">Week 40</option>
        <option value="2014-04-13">Week 41</option><option value="2014-04-20">Week 42</option><option value="2014-04-27">Week 43</option><option value="2014-05-04">Week 44</option>
        <option value="2014-05-11">Week 45</option><option value="2014-05-18">Week 46</option><option value="2014-05-25">Week 47</option><option value="2014-06-01">Week 48</option>
        <option value="2014-06-08">Week 49</option><option value="2014-06-15">Week 50</option><option value="2014-06-22">Week 51</option><option value="2014-06-29">Week 52</option>
```

I also have this code for my jquery datepicker, which displays the weeks correctly next to the date, but does not auto select the appropriate date depending on current week...

```
function myWeekCalc(date) {
    var checkDate = new Date(date.getTime());
    // Find
    checkDate.setDate(checkDate.getDate() + 185 - (checkDate.getDay()));
    var time = checkDate.getTime();
    checkDate.setMonth(0); // Compare with Jan 1
    checkDate.setDate(1);
    return Math.floor(Math.round((time - checkDate) / 86400000) / 7) + 1;
}

jQuery('input[name=selectweek1]').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    changeYear: true,
    changeMonth: true,
    firstDay: 1,
    calculateWeek: myWeekCalc,
    showWeek: true,
    minDate: new Date(2013, 6, 1),
    maxDate: new Date(2014, 5, 29)
});
```

**JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/a2nmR/**

Comment: create a demo in jsfiddle.net . Not clear what issue is , easier to help when able to play with code in console

Comment: roger, thank you charlie, i shall do so

Comment: Here is the Jsfiddle.net, although the datepicker is not working on the site for some reason??

http://jsfiddle.net/a2nmR/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) and [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/):

DEMO:
http://jsbin.com/aviVeyUW/3/edit

```
  $('#entryweek2 option').filter(function(index) { 
      return index === myWeekCalc(new Date());   
  }).prop('selected', true);
```

You can also do something like this:

DEMO:
http://jsbin.com/aviVeyUW/4/edit

```
$('#entryweek2 option').filter(function(index) { 
      var $this = $(this),
          today = new Date(),
          weekNo = parseInt($(this).text().split('Week ')[1]);
      return weekNo === myWeekCalc(today);
}).prop('selected', true);
```

Comment: Dom I've changed the format a little, as I only need to have a week selected and displayed in 1 combo box. I had it before with 2... Is there a way I could get the user to select a week (also have it defaulting from start), and have it return two dates (week start and finish) to be queried in an SQL statement?

Comment: Sorry, I am not following. Do you have a demo so I can get a better understanding of what you are looking for?

Comment: I posted a new question as you answered this one spot on, but I am asking something totally different now :D
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20342541/return-2-dates-from-single-combo-box-to-query-mysql-db